# How to make scrollbars in android browsers

Tags: javascript, css, overflow, android-browser, opera-mobile

How to use overflow-y in android browsers, for example in opera mobile? If I create a div with overflow-y style, thenn it wont work, like in the desktop browsers.

So I want to make vertical-scrollable div, without using any libraries.
Please give me some instructions.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make two divs:

```
<div class='parent-of-scroller'>
    <div class='scrollable-item'>
        ... your content ... 
    </div>
</div>
```

For outer div, set `overflow:hidden` control the placement of scroll position of internal div by managing its `margin-top` using javascript.  I believe you can make use of the touch events to control the scroll position of the internal div

Comment: Same problem here - but do not understand all of the solution. How do you "manage its margin-top using javascript"?

Comment: by managing the margin-top, I meant changing its integer value. You can negate it to scroll up (go below zero) and opposite way too.  You would have some event under which you will want to scroll the section and a number of pixels (xx) that determines how much you want to scroll.  Use `element.style.marginLeft="xx"`;

Answer (score 0):

For future posterity, Opera Mobile 12/Classic, the browser you tagged in your question, has  very specific criteria that must be followed in order to get `overflow: scroll` or `overflow: auto` to work:

> Element height (or width) alone is not enough to get Opera Mobile 12 to overflow an element and it will expand elements unless absolutely positioned with top and bottom values. This sucks but when absolutely positioned, Opera Mobile 12 does add a scrollbar to overflow elements but there is no support for touch gesture scrolling and the scrollbar controls are flaky.

So, to get Opera Mobile to *actually* add scrollbars and overflow a div you need to alter Kishu's example a little:

```
<style>
#parent-of-scroller {
  position: relative;
  height: [whatever]
}
#scrollable-item {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
}
</style>

<div class='parent-of-scroller'>
    <div class='scrollable-item'>
        ... your content ... 
    </div>
</div>
```

The Opera ≥9.5 CSS hack `_:-o-prefocus, body:last-child .your-selector-here` might assist you.

From http://barrow.io/overflow-scrolling